# How to generate this math typesetting

Tags: amsmath, typography

I would like to generate the following typesetting on the Q matrix:

[image: font]

However, the standard \mathscr or \mathcal do not generate this exact typesetting. Is there a specific font that I should load?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The calligraphic `Q` looks like the one from the `boondox` fonts. I can't exactly identify which Times clone the text/numbers use, so I go with `newtx` (but that's not really it as you see comparing the vertical positions of the numbers and the commas).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage[scr=boondox]{mathalfa}

\begin{document}
$\mathscr{Q}_1$, $\mathscr{Q}_2$, and $\mathscr{Q}_3$
\end{document}
```

[image]

With the option `scr=boondox` you'll get the glyphs with `\mathscr`. If you use `cal=boondox` the `\mathcal` alphabet will be redefined instead.